# Merging of two dictionaries

Tags: python

I have two dictionaries as follows:

`D1={'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}`

and

`D2={'b':2,'c':3,'d':1}`

I want to merge these two dictionaries and the result should be as follows:

`D3={'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'b':2,'c':3,'d':1}`

how can I achieve this in python?

Comment: `{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'b':2,'c':3,'d':1}` is not a Python dictionary.

Comment: what is it -am facing a similar issue

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I want to merge these two dictionaries and the result should be as
>   follows:
>
> D3={'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'b':2,'c':3,'d':1}
>
> how can I achieve this in python?

You can't. You can only have one value per key in a Python dict. What you can do is to have a list or a set as the value.

Here is an example with a set:

```
d1 = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }
d2 = { 'a': 1, 'b': 5, 'd': 4 }
d3 = {}
def add_dict(target, d):
    for key in d:
        target.setdefault(key, set([])).add(d[key])

add_dict(d3, d1)
add_dict(d3, d2)
```

This will give you `d3`:

```
{'a': set([1]), 'c': set([3]), 'b': set([2, 5]), 'd': set([4])}
```

You can also do this with a list (possibly closer to your example):

```
d1 = { 'a':1, 'b':2, 'c': 3}
d2 = { 'b':2 ,'c':3, 'd': 1}
d3 = {}
def add_dict(target, d):
    for key in d:
        target.setdefault(key, []).append(d[key])

add_dict(d3, d1)
add_dict(d3, d2)
```

You'll get this:

```
{'a': [1], 'c': [3, 3], 'b': [2, 2], 'd': [1]}
```

However, looking at `{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'b':2,'c':3,'d':1}` (which can't be a dict), it seems that you're after a different data structure altogether. Perhaps something like this:

```
d1 = { 'a':1, 'b':2, 'c': 3}
d2 = { 'b':2 ,'c':3, 'd': 1}
result = []

result += [ { 'key': key, 'value': d1[key] } for key in d1 ]
result += [ { 'key': key, 'value': d2[key] } for key in d2 ]
```

This would produce this, which looks closer to the data structure you had in mind initially:

```
[ {'value': 1, 'key': 'a'},
  {'value': 3, 'key': 'c'},
  {'value': 2, 'key': 'b'},
  {'value': 3, 'key': 'c'},
  {'value': 2, 'key': 'b'},
  {'value': 1, 'key': 'd'} ]
```

Comment: I tested this and seem to be missing something, as I literally typed: type({0.8080260303687652: 2e-05,
   0.8069414316702677: 1e-05,
   0.8091106290672485: 1e-05,
   0.8156182212581342: 1e-05}) , and got the result 'dict'. So apparently it can be a dictionary?

Comment: @El_1988 unless I'm missing something, all the keys are different in your example. You only have one value per key.

Answer (score 6):

You may want to try:

```
D3 = {}
D3.update(D1)
D3.update(D2)
```

Here, we're creating an empty dictionary `D3` first, then update it from the two other dictionaries.

Note that you need to be careful with the order of the updates: if `D2` shares some keys with `D1`, the code above will overwrite the corresponding entries of `D1` with those of `D2`.

Note as well that the keys will **not** be repeated. The example you give `D3={a:1,b:2,c:3,b:2,c:3,d:1}` is not a valid dictionary.

Comment: +1 -- But if you type `D3={a:1,b:2,c:3,b:2,c:3,d:1}` into the interpreter, It'll happily allow it (provided that `a,b,c,d` are defined and hashable).  It *is* a valid expression to construct *a* dictionary as far as I know (although I'm not sure if the standard explicitly states whether you take the first value for a repeated key or the last one, or if it is "random").

Answer (score 4):

Dictionaries by definition can't have duplicate keys, so "merging" dictionaries will actually give the following result (note the order is arbitrary):

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 1}
```

You can create a clone of one of the dictionaries and merge the entries from the other into it:

```
D3 = dict(D1)
D3.update(D2)
```

or you can create a new dictionary from the concatenation of the (key, value) tuples from each input dictionary:

```
D3 = dict(D1.items() + D2.items())
```

If you really want multiple values for duplicate keys, you need something like a list of values for each key:

```
from itertools import groupby
dict(( (key, [v for k, v in group]) for key, group in groupby(sorted(D1.items() + D2.items()), lambda x: x[0])))
```

Answer (score 2):

What are you asking is not possible, since you cannot have two different keys with the same value in a Python dictionary.

The closest answer to your question is:

`D3 = dict( D1.items() + D2.items() )`

Note: if you have different values for the same key, the ones from D2 will be the ones in D3.

Example:
`D1 = { 'a':1, 'b'=2 }`
 `D2 = { 'c':3, 'b':3}`
Then, D3 will be:
     `D3= { 'a':1, 'b':3, 'c':3 }`

Answer (score 2):

```
In [3]: D1={'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}

In [4]: D2={'b':2,'c':3,'d':1}

In [5]: D1.update(D2)

In [6]: D1
Out[6]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 1}
```

**Update**

Alternative solutions

```
In [9]: D3=D1.copy()

In [10]: D3.update(D2)

In [11]: D3
Out[11]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 1}

In [12]: D4=dict(D1, **D2)
```

or

```
In [13]: D4
Out[13]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 1}
```

or

```
In [16]: D5 = dict(D1.items() + D2.items())

In [17]: D5
Out[17]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 1}
```

Comment: ... which modifies `D1`. It may be wiser to make a copy first.

Comment: true, just a quick session in ipython; 4 more or less identical answers here :-)